# select option and hide div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I've been searching without luck a solution to this...Im trying to do a function that hide a div on an selected option in a select box but I cant make it work properly, I mean, it works if I refresh the page with the option that hide the div selected, the div is hided, I change option, the div is visible, BUT if I come back to the option that should hide the div... it doesnt hide it... What Im doing wrong?

This is my function:

```js
    $(function(){

        if ( $('select#CW_Type').val() ==='APPROVED' ) {
            $('#creditLimit').addClass('hide');
            $('select#CW_Type').on("change",function() {
                $('#creditLimit').removeClass('hide');
            });
        
    };
});
```

the id "#creditLimit" is the div that should be hided and then be showed again 
This is my HTML

```html
<div>
        <label>
            Type 
            <select id="CW_Type" name="CW_Type">
                <option  value="-">-</option>
                <option  value="APPROVED">APPROVED</option>
                <option  value="LIMIT">LIMIT</option>
                <option value="MANUAL_DECISION">MANUAL DECISION</option>
                <option class="selected" value="DENIED">DENIED</option>
            </select>
        </label>
</div>

    <div id="creditLimit" class="span6">

        <label class="half">
            Credit Limit
            <input type="number" name="CW_CreditLimit" value="0" min="0" step="1" data-validate="currency">
        </label>

        <label class="half">
            Currency
            <select name="CW_Currency">
                <option value="-">-</option>
                <option value="SEK">SEK</option>
                <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>

<style>
.hide {display:none;}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Comment: Looks like In your Javascript is the first line missing... an please provide one single snippet with proper HTML, CSS and Javascript in the suitable parts...

Answer (score 1):

You need a `change` function for the `select`, then check the value and do your logic:

```
$("select#CW_Type").change(function() {
    if ( this.value ==='APPROVED' ) {
        $('#creditLimit').addClass('hide');
    } else {
        $('#creditLimit').removeClass('hide');
    }
}).change(); //call on load
```

You currently have a `change` handler - but it's only being bound when your `if` condition is satisfied - and if that isn't on load, then the handler will never be bound.

Comment: Sorry about the snippet! I promise I'll start to do it right :) And thanks a lot for your answer! That made it perfectly right!!